# Obatining Rotation Matrix from glRotatef() in opengl

Tags: c, opengl, rotation

Is there a way to get the rotation matrix which is generated by command `glRotatef()` in opengl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can get the current matrix with `glGetFloatv`. If you want just the rotation matrix, I think you should compute it yourself.

Comment: @NicolBolas The link seems to be broken now.

Answer (score 1):

```
float modelViewMatrix[16]; 
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelViewMatrix);
```

Note: the model view matrix must be initialized to the identity matrix before calls to rotate etc.

Comment: How can I use modelview matrix to get rotation matrix?

Comment: The upper left 3x3 matrix inside the modelview matrix is the rotation matrix.

Comment: -1: This gets the current modelview matrix. The rotation generated by glRotatef is multiplied by the current modelview. So you'd only be getting the rotation matrix if you had `glLoadIdentity`'d it before.

Comment: I was assuming it was initialized to the identity matrix before hand.